# Problem getting data for local storage - Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to make a form to allow the user to save a Track item in Local Storage. But I'm getting this error : **Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value** 
On the line 36, where I'm putting a datePicker inside a text field.

So I'm trying to get kms, liters from TextField.text and date from this field and a picture from camera.

```
import UIKit

class TrackListController : UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    self.imageData = NSData()
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

    var TrackItems = [TrackingItem]()
    var imageData: NSData

    @IBOutlet weak var kmsTextField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var litersTextField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var ImagePreview: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var textFieldPicker: UITextField!
    private var datePicker: UIDatePicker!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        datePicker = UIDatePicker()
        datePicker?.datePickerMode = .date
        datePicker?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(TrackListController.dateChanged(datePicker:)), for: .valueChanged)

        textFieldPicker.inputView = datePicker

        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(TrackListController.viewTapped(gestureRecogniser:)))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    }



    func tableView(_tableView: UITableView, numberofRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
        return TrackItems.count
    }


    @objc func viewTapped (gestureRecogniser: UITapGestureRecognizer){

        view.endEditing(true)

    }

    @objc func dateChanged (datePicker: UIDatePicker){

        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
        textFieldPicker.text = dateFormatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
        //view.endEditing(true)

    }

    @IBAction func takePhoto(_ sender: Any) {
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerController.SourceType.camera){
            let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
            imagePicker.delegate = self
            imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerController.SourceType.camera
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
            self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

        //Getting the image token from Camera

        let  pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage
        ImagePreview.contentMode = .scaleToFill

        //Putting the camera into the UIImageView for preview

        ImagePreview.image = pickedImage

        //Encoding the image 

        imageData = pickedImage!.pngData()! as NSData
    }

    @IBAction func SaveNewTrackItem(_ sender: Any) {
        let trackItem = TrackingItem(context: PersistenceSerivce.context)
        trackItem.kms = kmsTextField.text
        trackItem.liters = litersTextField.text
        //trackItem.date = textFieldPicker.text
        trackItem.image = imageData
        PersistenceSerivce.saveContext()
        self.TrackItems.append(trackItem)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: Line 36 doesn't seem to be related to text fields or date pickers, do you mean this line: `textFieldPicker.inputView = datePicker`

Comment: Have you check that the connections are ok in your storyboard for `textFieldPicker`?

Comment: Yes everything is connected good, even the build is successful and everything works on simumator but when I try to open the scene connected to this controller I have the fatal error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not use optional (?= operator for datePicker that you declared as an Explicitly Unwrapped Variable :

```
private var datePicker: UIDatePicker!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    datePicker = UIDatePicker()
    datePicker.datePickerMode = .date
    datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(TrackListController.dateChanged(datePicker:)), for: .valueChanged)

    textFieldPicker.inputView = datePicker
    [...]
```

Comment: @MarouenAbdi same error on same line "textFieldPicker.inputView = datePicker" ?

Comment: Yes same line. 
Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Then you have to check in the Storyboard (or in the Xib) if the connection is active: ( the IBOutlet should be loaded when the view is loaded, it gives you error because it is nil in that moment)